# M2Eclipse & workspace project

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse, workspace

In Eclipse Helios, the m2eclipse plugin doesn't include projects in my local workspace in any run configuration.

I've set up this test scenario:

```
ProjectA
+ src/main/java/a/TestInA.java
+ pom.xml

ProjectB
+ src/main/java/b/TestInB.java ("main()" calls "a.TestInA.main()")
+ pom.xml (includes reference to ProjectA)
```

The flag "Resolve dependencies from Workspace projects" is set on both projects. This works beautifully while compiling, i.e. compiler finds reference to "a.TestInA" in "b.TestInB", and the "Maven dependencies" list includes a reference to "ProjectA". But when I try to actually run "b.TestInB", I get a NoClassDefFoundError:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: a/TestInA
at b.TestInB.main(TestInB.java:13)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: a.TestInA
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
... 1 more
```

Indeed, the system property "java.class.path" doesn't include ProjectA's "target/classes" folder (or any other folder for that matter).

These are my installed versions:

- Eclipse: Helios Service Release 2 (build id: 20110301-1815)
- m2eclipse: 0.12.1 (build id: 20110112-1712)

Comment: how do you run your app? via maven?

Comment: I let Eclipse start the app using a "Run configuration". The classpath for this "Run configuration" includes the "Maven dependencies" entry. Any third-party libraries I use are included in this entry, but not the project dependency. And to top it off, when I run a test class, the "ProjectA/target/test-classes" **is** included...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found the error in my configuration. It had to do with the "archiverClassifier" in the workspace dependency. My POMs are set up to generate differently named artifacts depending on the running compiler.

This is done using profiles for "jdk1.5" and "jdk1.6", setting the "archiverClassifier" variable:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>jdk1.5</id>
        <activation>
            <jdk>1.5</jdk>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <compilerTarget>1.5</compilerTarget>
            <archiverClassifier>jdk1.5</archiverClassifier>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>jdk1.6</id>
        <activation>
            <jdk>1.6</jdk>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <compilerTarget>1.6</compilerTarget>
            <archiverClassifier>jdk1.6</archiverClassifier>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Then, in the dependency, I refer to the correct classifier using the "classifier" child, giving it the "archiverClassifier" variable previously set in the corresponding profile:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.brain2</groupId>
        <artifactId>ProjectA</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <classifier>${archiverClassifier}</classifier>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

If I remove the "classifier" child, m2eclipse's workspace dependency resolution works like a charm.

Once I figured this out, a quick Google-search for "m2eclipse workspace resolution classifiers" landed me square on Sonatype's JIRA page for bug [MNGECLIPSE-680](https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/MNGECLIPSE-680). So I guess this is a bug, and I just answered my own question :)

(On a side note, this issue doesn't arise for unit tests, where the dependency's "test-classes" directory is properly added to the classpath.)

Answer (score 0):

Remember that Maven uses the local repository to share JARs. If you haven't installed (mvn install) module A then module B (which depends on module A) will not be aware of it. The IDE is quietly compensating for this behind the scenes.

Comment: The "Resolve workspace dependencies" flag takes care of this while compiling, but not while running? This doesn't make sense. Besides, it works when using "mvn eclipse:eclipse" instead of m2eclipse. How do you explain that?

Comment: @Wim When you run your project, are you invoking the internal Eclipse managed Maven or are you calling out to an external (CLI) version?

Comment: @Gary: I'm using the built-in Maven.

Comment: @Wim Final check - if you run mvn install on Module A, and then immediately repeat your execution of module B does it work?

Comment: @Gary: when I install ProjectA's JAR artifact and disable workspace resolution, ProjectB runs successfully. (I figured that out before, but I really don't want to install every dependency artifact for my live environment...)

Comment: @Wim Fair enough - but what it's pointing to is that somewhere along the line in your configuration, Maven is being forced to refer to the local repository to share the information which is the normal Maven build process.

Comment: Well, ProjectA's pom.xml is [here](http://pastebin.com/BXDcFhJX) and ProjectB's is [here](http://pastebin.com/2VMWJwXC).

Comment: @Gary: thanks for your help with this! I finally figured it out, see my own answer below.

Comment: @Wim Glad to see you've published the answer - should be useful for others :-)